# Align swiffy-Stage to the right side of page

Tags: css, html, google-swiffy

I have a flash scene converted with Google swiffy to html5.
All is fine but I can't get the scene (or stage) align to the right side of the page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Swiffy output</title>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v4.9/runtime.js"></script>
<script>
swiffyobject = {"tags":[{"bounds":.........HERE IS THE SWIFFY-CODE..........
</script>
<style>html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%}</style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden">
<div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 800px; height: 310px">
</div>
<script>
var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
swiffyobject);
stage.start();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help? I think it's very easy for HTML-specialists - but I can't solve
this little problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the script is what you want to align... if not ill take it as an example

With `float:right;` you can make it float to the right

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <script>
    var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
    swiffyobject);
    stage.start();
    </script>
</div>
```

a other option is `text-align:right;`

```
<div style="text-align:right; width:100%;">
    <script>
    var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
    swiffyobject);
    stage.start();
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: text-align:right; doesn't work .... I don't know why, but it works fine with the float-solution!
Thanks a lot for your fast help!

Answer (score 0):

If you find this page because you were looking how to CENTER the swiffy animation then;

```
#swiffycontainer { margin:0 auto; }
```

Works great for me.